# Laravel project from localhost to server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to put my laravel project from localhost to server. On my localhost I run it as this:

```
http://localhost/nih/public/bassengweb/hvertime
```

But when I uploaded it to the server:

```
http://student.cs.hioa.no/~s180393/nih/public/bassengweb/hvertime
```

I get this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, amirahm@cs.hioa.no and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Comment: You're going to have to look at the server logs and see what the error is. Could be any number of things - missing PHP feature, permissions issue, etc.

Comment: Hmm! I will have to check that.

Comment: I'd nod towards permissions issue, "sudo chmod 0777 -R app/storage" from the project root is a very common solution. Once that's writable, "php artisan tail", also from the project root is a quick way to get to Laravel's error log for any further problems.

Answer (score 0):

thats not a laravel issue but a server issue. So lets trace it, according to your error information its a mostly is a configuration issue.

Set the server to read from the public folder and not the root.